# C# Print the values of all members of an object

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to iterate through an object and print all the values for each member of said object.

I've created a test program below

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    public int  Salary { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public ICollection<ContactInfo> contactInfo { get; set; }
    public EmployeeValue value { get; set; }
    public Employee()
    {
        contactInfo = new List<ContactInfo>();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public bool IsMale { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeValue
{
    public int IQ { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

I then seed the object with some test data. After the object is populated, I attempt to iterate through all members and display their value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Seed initSeed = new Seed();
        object obj = initSeed.getSomebody();
        foreach (var p in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {

            DisplayProperties(p, obj);

        }           

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

static void DisplayProperties(PropertyInfo p, object obj)
    {
        Type tColl = typeof(ICollection<>);

        Type t = p.PropertyType;
        // If this is a collection of objects
        if (t.IsGenericType && tColl.IsAssignableFrom(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) ||
            t.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == tColl))
        {
            System.Collections.IList a = (System.Collections.IList)p.GetValue(obj, null);
            foreach (var b in a)
            {
                foreach(PropertyInfo x in b.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    DisplayProperties(x, b);
                }
            }

        }
        // If this is a custom object
        else if (Convert.ToString(t.Namespace) != "System")
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo nonPrimitive in t.GetProperties())
            {

                DisplayProperties(nonPrimitive, obj);
            }
        }
           // if this is .net framework object
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs when the namespace is != "System" ie, it is a custom object. As seen in this line; `else if (Convert.ToString(t.Namespace) != "System")`

After the function recurses and makes it to the final else statement, I get

> "Object does not match target type."

Somehow, I need to get an object reference to the inner object.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: For clarity, the obj object seeded in Main is an Employee

Comment: No, I may have been unclear. The code will enter the 
    else if (Convert.ToString(t.Namespace) != "System")
then it will find each propertyinfo for the nested custom object, which in this case will be EmployeeValue

It will recurse upon itself. The next iteration of the recursion will bring it to the final else statement

    else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(obj, null));
            }

at this point an exception will be called because the object obj does not match the target type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
DisplayProperties(nonPrimitive, obj);
```

to

```
DisplayProperties(nonPrimitive, p.GetValue(obj, null));
```

However, this will work only if

```
EmployeeValue value {get;set;}
```

is not null. Otherwise it'll throw another exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the toSting() method for the class Employee.

[Overridind toString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx)

Then the Employee will know how to display itself. And it can be printed on the Console

```
Console.WriteLine(employee);
```